# How to delete beta "update is available" after unenrolling from beta?

Tags: beta, big-sur

I unenrolled from macOS Big Sur beta program, however I am still getting the 11.0.1 "update is available" notification. I would like to remove this so that I upgrade directly to 11.0 when GM is released. I don't want to install 11.0.1. Is there a way to delete cached update data so I only get 11.0 when it's eventually released?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unenrolling your AppleID from the beta program is not the same as unenrolling a specific device. Did you follow any of these steps? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406288/5472

Comment: This is not a duplicate question; in [Update from macOS Big Sur public Beta to official release](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406286/update-from-macos-big-sur-public-beta-to-official-release/406288#406288) the user did not unenrolled the device. There we see no option for unenrolling the device (so it has been done already), and the Beta update is still proposed.

Comment: I have the same issue, any update on the question?

Answer (score 1):

The following Terminal command will stop your Mac from accessing the software update catalog for Beta software:

```
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate CatalogURL
```

You might need a restart, or relaunch of System Prefs and Command R to reload the Software Update pane at least.

Comment: It comes back with a `Domain (/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate) not found` error

Comment: Have you restarted? Are you still being offered the update?

Comment: Yup, restarted and it insists on updating my mac to 11.0.1

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Luckily, you're in the Beta programme, so you can report it easily....!

Comment: Same issue here. I reported the bug with the Feedback Assistant, waiting for an update.The file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate` is also not found on my machine.