# Update from macOS Big Sur public Beta to official release

Tags: software-update, beta, beta-seed-program, big-sur

My MacBookPro is currently running macOS Big Sur Version 11.0 Beta. Now that an official release for Big Sur has arrived, is it possible to move to the public release, just like a regular software update?

In the "Software Update" settings, it still looks like I am suggested to install the new Beta version, rather than the official release.

How should I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405313/how-to-delete-beta-update-is-available-after-unenrolling-from-beta?rq=1 help?

Comment: Kinda. The thing is that I would not like to definitively stop your Mac from accessing the Beta softwares in the future, but simply to switch to the public releases, when they are available, possibly avoiding reinstalling the whole software from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Release Candidate 2 is equivalent to the actual final release. You should install it, then un-enroll from the beta program. When a future version of Big Sur is released, you will not be given betas and will go directly to the final release. Click "Details" to be given the option to stop receiving beta updates.

You may be prompted to install another update after un-enrolling. If you do, this ensures you're on the public release.

Comment: I am still getting a 11.1 Beta update after un-enrolling.

Comment: @koo I'm also getting this - did you unenroll after the update appeared? Unsure how to avoid it without simply turning off auto-updates.

Answer (score 3):

The public beta FAQ covers how to de-enroll from beta builds.

- https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/faq

See the Support section.

> At any time, you may unenroll your device so that it no longer receives these updates. Then, when the next version of commercial software is released, you can install it from iOS Software Update, the Mac App Store, tvOS Software Update or watchOS Software Update.

https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/unenroll

Comment: It doesn't always work though. I unenrolled as described there but Software Update still wants to give me the 11.1 beta.